# JRuby JDBC setup for rake db:migrate task

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, sinatra, jruby, sinatra-activerecord

I had a ruby Sinatra app and `gem pg` to use some Java open source applications, I switched to jruby. This is the output for `jruby -S rake db:migrate`.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `get_oid_type' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::JdbcAdapter:0x294f9d50>
api/tasks/db.rake:18:in `block in (root)'
```

***rake file***

```
require 'active_record'
require 'jdbc/postgresql'

namespace :db do
  task(:environment) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'jdbc',
    :driver => 'org.postgresql.Driver',
    :url => 'jdbc:postgresql:db_name',
    :username => 'username',
    :password => 'password'
    )
  end

  desc 'Migrate the MOT core models (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false)'
  task :migrate => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = true
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../db/migrate", ENV['VERSION'] ? ENV['VERSION'].to_i : nil
  end

  desc 'Rolls the schema back to the previous version of MOT core model(specify steps w/ STEP=n).'
  task :rollback => :environment do
    step = ENV['STEP'] ? ENV['STEP'].to_i : 1
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.rollback "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../db/migrate", ENV['VERSION'] ? ENV['VERSION'].to_i : step
  end
end
```

***db.rake:#18***

ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate "#{File.dirname(**FILE**)}/../db/migrate", ENV['VERSION'] ? ENV['VERSION'].to_i : nil

I am running postgresql with jdbc.

***UPDATE***

I add the postgresql.jar to my jruby path (jruby installed by brew in my mac) and I am getting the same error. I also removed the jar file and I had driver not found error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution.

First make sure you have the followings in your ***`Gemfile`***

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', :require => 'arjdbc'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
```

then in your **db migrate task** this is the setup for environment:

```
task(:environment) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'jdbcpostgresql',
    :driver => 'org.postgresql.Driver',
    :url => 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME'
    )
  end
```

Also this is the ***`database.yaml`*** for development:

```
development:
    adapter: jdbcpostgresql
    driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    encoding: unicode
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
    username: USER_NAME
    password: PASSWORD
```

Enjoy your JDBC with Jruby on Sinatra application !!!!

Comment: I really don't understand who gave -1 to this, since this was working 100% for me,

Answer (score 0):

simply use **adapter: postgresql** in your configuration and it should work just fine.

Comment: your call - the issue is your duplicating your database configuration, which will likely bite you in the end. essentially the problem seems to be loading AR's tasks which work with MRI instead of ones available in AR-JDBC ... so a "good" answer should resolve that!

Comment: Anyways, I am not accepting this solution, since this doesn't work for me.